# asp net forms authentication cannot login on two application in same time on same server

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, form-authentication

I created two ASP.NET Web Forms Application in which I use separate Form authentication
with different machine keys .
But when I login in one of them I am logout in other.
Same thing happen on production server and on localhost.

Comment: Right. That's how it works by default. So... your question?

Comment: I want to be login in same time on both application.

Comment: Sounds like you don't actually have them separated onto different apps. Could you describe your setup some so we have some idea how to help?

Comment: I created one application year ago. Now I created new application with separate Form authentication in separate database. And I can't be login on both app in same time. Is it possible I have problem with cookie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't configured at least one of the two applications to use a non-default cookie name, they will both try to use the same cookie name ".ASPXAUTH", and if by "on the same server" you mean they are accessed using the same hostname, then logging into one will overwrite the cookie of the other.

Try overriding the cookie name in your Web.config, something like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".FOOASPXAUTH" />
</authentication>
```

And in the other application:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".BARASPXAUTH" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: @Sloba: glad to hear it!